# Bug with sending incorrect json doc

Tags: c++, json, segmentation-fault, std, oat++

I am testing example-crud for applying your framework in my project. But I noticed some bug.
I try to get value from the sent json into std::string with this way:
**std::string test = userDto->userName->c_str();**

```
ENDPOINT("POST", "users", createUser,  BODY_DTO(Object<UserDto>, userDto))
{
       std::string test = userDto->userName->c_str();

       return createDtoResponse(Status::CODE_200, m_userService.createUser(userDto));
}
```

UserDto defined like this:

```
class UserDto : public oatpp::DTO {
    DTO_INIT(UserDto, DTO)
    DTO_FIELD(Int32, id);
    DTO_FIELD(String, userName, "username");
};
```

If i send correct json with post query, i get value to "test" variable properly.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "username": "test_user"
}
```

But if i change json`s field "username" to, as example, "Username" and send this json to endpoin, server will faild with error "Segmentation fault".

Server must'n faild under such condition. It must giv error message to the sender, and continue run.

How can i avoid the failure, if i just neen to get one simple value to variable?

Comment: Where exactly does it cause the "segmentation fault"? Run the code in a debugger to find out! If that doesn't help, extract a [mcve] from your code and include that in your question here as is actually required. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: This is no bug. It correct to adding OATPP_ASSERT_HTTP(userDto->userName, Status::CODE_400, "username is required!");  before std::string test = userDto->userName->c_str();

Answer (score 1):

Since the DTO field name and the JSON-key doesn't match, the `userName` of the received DTO is `null`. So the solution would be to add a `nullptr` check:

```
ENDPOINT("POST", "users", createUser,  
         BODY_DTO(Object<UserDto>, userDto)) 
{
  OATPP_ASSERT_HTTP(userDto->userName, Status::CODE_400, "username is required!"); // check field for nullptr
  std::string test = userDto->userName->std_str();
  ...
  return createDtoResponse(Status::CODE_200, m_userService.createUser(userDto));
}
```

Source:  https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/issues/340#issuecomment-727563144