# Oat++ framework. Seg fault from getting value of the json parsed to DTO object field. Assertion for ALL fileds at once

Tags: c++, json, oat++

**MAIN POINT of my question in the end of the text**

Okay, I ran into a common problem: if I send JSON without some key:value pair to my oat++ server, parse it with BODY_DTO in my ENDPOINT and then try to get value of non-exist filed, I will get segmentation fault and my server will immediately crush

My controller endpoint:

```
ENDPOINT("POST", "/servers/{serverId}", getServerById,
                    PATH(String, serverId, "serverId"), BODY_DTO(Object<MyDTO>, body)) {
            try{
                std::cout << "body->noInJSONField : " << body->noInJSONField <<std::endl;
            } catch(std::exception& exc) {
                std::cout << exc.what() <<std::endl;
            }
}
```

My DTO:

```
class MyDTO : public oatpp::DTO {

  DTO_INIT(MyDTO, DTO  )

  DTO_FIELD(Int16, inJSONField, "inJSONField");     // 
  DTO_FIELD(Int16, noInJSONField, "noInJSONField");
  DTO_FIELD(Object<MyANOTHER_DTO>, smallDerivedJSONobjInMainJsonObj, "emmUhhOkay");
}
```

Extremely important in my problem that I know about similar question on stackOverflow:

[Bug with sending incorrect json doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844227/bug-with-sending-incorrect-json-doc)

And the same on GitHub:

https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/issues/340#issuecomment-727563144

So, my question: is there any way to assert (Maybe some OATPP_ASSERT_ALL_FIELDS(%DTO_OBJ%))
**all fields** of my objects (And all fields of included objects in my DTO like third field)?

Why am I asking? Because check all fileds like

```
OATPP_ASSERT(body);
OATPP_ASSERT(body->inJSONField);
OATPP_ASSERT(body->noInJSONField);
OATPP_ASSERT(body->smallDerivedJSONobjInMainJsonObj);
OATPP_ASSERT(body->smallDerivedJSONobjInMainJsonObj->field1);
OATPP_ASSERT(body->smallDerivedJSONobjInMainJsonObj->field2);
OATPP_ASSERT(body->smallDerivedJSONobjInMainJsonObj->field3_obj->wow_another_field);
```

feels exactly as it looks - utterly cumbersome

Comment: Sounds like you need an XML schema, but JSON doesn't have any equivalent AFAIK.

Comment: @john , if there is no convenient solution for this situation I think using third-party library specially for parsing json is only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, in the DTO definition just force the required field(s), like this:

```
DTO_FIELD_INFO(noInJSONField) { 
    info->required = true; }
```

OAT++ will catch the missing field(s) and will answer with an explicit error.